# How can I check if a temp table exists using ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have some code I've written that creates a number of temp tables, and I'm trying to check that the temp tables don't exist before I create them.

Currently, the code uses `SqlConnection.GetSchema` to look for the tables, but that doesn't seem to return temp tables.

Does anyone know of a clean way I can do this, apart from querying `tempdb` or trying to query the table and looking for exceptions?

Comment: In a nut shell execute `SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#YourTempTableName')`, if the result is not `DBNull.Value` then the table exists, otherwise it does not.

Comment: I was looking for a way to do this in pure C#, similar to `GetSchema`.  However, that will work if there's no better way.